# CakePHP and MySQL fetching records: a handful at a time or hundreds in a row

Tags: php, mysql, performance, cakephp, datatables

I'm developing an application using the framework [CakePHP](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/index.html), with MySQL as database.

- The maximum number of records to fetch from a table are not more than 2000.
- To show in an index page, I'm fetching the whole 2000.
- For pagination I use the JavaScript [DataTables plugin](https://datatables.net/).
- The user base of the application is no more than 10 users.

I found that the delay fetching the 2000 +/- records is negligible in page loading. And as all the records are in the client's side, making searches via DataTables without any delay.

Modern web browsers and internet speeds seems to handle this amount of data without a blink.

1. Discussing with some colleagues, they told me that I should paginate fetching, 10 (for example) records at a time, making a query to the server each 10 rows.
2. My take on this is that fetching 10 records at a time (I'm not using Ajax), could hurt the user experience, since implies a delay in every click and in every search. Also seems to me that the server side performance and efficiency is not really something serious in this case.

Taking into account all of these considerations, what of these two options is the correct one?

---

<sup>I posted in meta [a question about the scope of the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363478/question-with-multiple-topics-site-recommendation). I can edit to be narrower if needed.</sup>

Comment: Will the records change often and does data need to be realtime available? Caching all records is a possibilty otherwise. Refresh the cache at an interval of your choice. It will also reduce load on your database server

Comment: @Daan * - Will the records change often - *, no, they are almost static. Yes, it needs to be realtime available.

Comment: In that case, cache it and refresh the cache whenever data changes.

Comment: Implement it and time it.  If it is "fast enough" you are done.  There are too many unknowns for us to provide you with a reliable opinion -- the query, the schema, how the JS package works, the expectations of the users, the latency between client and server, etc, etc.